# How do I pass multiple attributes into an Angular.js attribute directive?

Tags: javascript, parameters, angularjs, attributes, directive

I have an attribute directive restricted as follows:

```
 restrict: "A"
```

I need to pass in two attributes; a number and a function/callback, accessing them within the directive using the `attrs` object.

If the directive was an element directive, restricted with `"E"` I could to this:

```
<example-directive example-number="99" example-function="exampleCallback()">
```

However, for reasons I won't go into I need the directive to be an attribute directive.

**How do I pass multiple attributes into an attribute directive?**

Comment: That depends on the type of scope your directive creates (if any).  Choices are: no new scope (default, or explicit with `scope: false`), new scope (with normal prototypal inheritance, i.e., `scope: true`), and isolate scope (i.e., `scope: { ... }`).  What type of scope does your directive create?

Comment: @MarkRajcok It has an isolate scope.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The directive can access any attribute that is defined on the same element, even if the directive itself is not the element.

Template:

```
<div example-directive example-number="99" example-function="exampleCallback()"></div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('exampleDirective ', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',   // 'A' is the default, so you could remove this line
        scope: {
            callback : '&exampleFunction',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var num = scope.$eval(attrs.exampleNumber);
            console.log('number=',num);
            scope.callback();  // calls exampleCallback()
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/wTz4b/)</kbd>

If the value of attribute `example-number` will be hard-coded, I suggest using [`$eval`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$eval) once, and storing the value.  Variable `num` will have the correct type (a number).

Comment: I've edited the example HTML to use snake-case. I know I can't use it as an element. That's the point of the question.

Comment: @Pedr, yeah, sorry I read too fast about the element usage.  I updated the answer, noting that you also need to use snake-case for the attributes too.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your answer. I've edited the attribute names to use snake-case. You OK if I remove that from your answer as it was just a silly error by me and distracts from the point of the actual question and answer?

Comment: I don't get this - how does the directive know to name the exact same thing specified in the directive usage ("exampleCallback()") in its scope?  ("callback : '&exampleCallback')  Shouldn't the scope be "callback : "&exampleFunction" ?

Comment: Does this work even if there are multiple directives on the same element?

Comment: @FredrikL, for multiple directives on the same element, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28735005/215945

Comment: I had this same requirement, except I had to pass in a string array of values.  This code gave me the starting point to get it working!  Thanks Mark!

Comment: How can I get `exampleNumber` in controller (updated value, not that which was at the time of creating directive) without defining it in scope parameters?

Answer (score 20):

You do it exactly the same way as you would with an element directive. You will have them in the attrs object, my sample has them two-way binding via the isolate scope but that's not required. If you're using an isolated scope you can access the attributes with `scope.$eval(attrs.sample)` or simply scope.sample, but they may not be defined at linking depending on your situation.

```
app.directive('sample', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'sample' : '=',
            'another' : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
            scope.$watch('sample', function (newVal) {
                console.log('sample', newVal);
            });
            scope.$watch('another', function (newVal) {
                console.log('another', newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

used as:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<input type="text" ng-model="something" placeholder="Enter something here">
<div sample="name" another="something"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You could pass an object as attribute and read it into the directive like this:

```
<div my-directive="{id:123,name:'teo',salary:1000,color:red}"></div>

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {            
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           //convert the attributes to object and get its properties
           var attributes = scope.$eval(attrs.myDirective);       
           console.log('id:'+attributes.id);
           console.log('id:'+attributes.name);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to send a boolean value using a object? I tried `{{true}}` but it still returns the string value `true`.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me and I think is more HTML5 compliant.  You should change your html to use 'data-' prefix

```
<div data-example-directive data-number="99"></div>
```

And within the directive read the variable's value:

```
scope: {
        number : "=",
        ....
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you "require" 'exampleDirective' from another directive + your logic is in 'exampleDirective's' controller (let's say 'exampleCtrl'):

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        bindToController: {
            myCallback: '&exampleFunction'
        },
        controller: 'exampleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
});
app.controller('exampleCtrl', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myCallback();
});
```