# How to prevent scope collision between angularjs directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a simple directive, called `match` that is used like:

```
<input match='pattern' />
```

The declaration line of my directive is:

```
app.directive('match', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            pattern: '=match'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            // doing stuff here
        }
    };
});
```

However, after a while I wanted to use BootstrapUI for angularjs, and as soon as I started using typeahead component, they encountered a problem on using the same scope:

> Multiple directives [match, uibTypeaheadMatch] asking for new/isolated scope on

I need `match`, and typeahead together in one page. Typeahead is not under my control, and I don't want to change `match`'s name.

What can I do to prevent their collision?

Comment: For this simple case you can declare `scope: false` to use whatever scope is available and parse the attribute (even maybe watch it) yourself using the `$parse` service. In general this is a problem indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366762/angular-1-2-no-longer-allows-multiple-isolated-scope-directives-on-same-element I think your issue is not a naming clash, but the fact angular can't have multiple isolated scopes on the same element

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both your directive and Typeahead directive, are asking for isolated scope on the same element and angular does not allow it.

To overcome this problem, define the directive in a different way:

```
app.directive('match', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            var match = attributes.match;
            //do your stuff
        }
    };
});
```