# pass data from controller to directive's link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

In my controller :

```
myApp.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state,  'red';
    $rootScope.$on('new_story', function(event, data) {
        $scope.cardObj = {key:'value'};
    });
});
```

In my HTML :

```
<div clickmeee ></div>
<div id="feedContainer" card='{{cardObj}}'> </div>
```

In my directive :

```
myApp.directive('clickmeee', function($compile, $rootScope) {

            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    card: '@'
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.bind('click', function() {   
                            scope.$watch('card', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                                alert(scope.card);
                            });         
                            });
                        }
                    };
                });
```

How do I pass data from controller to this directive. I compile some html and prepend it to the div. All of that is sorted out but I need some data from object I am trying to pass.

Any help??

Comment: Your scope attribute is named `card`. But you're watching and alerting `'cardObj'`.

Comment: You should not put watcher on click event..on click of element multiple watchers will get added..

Comment: Have you looked at `$emit` and `$broadcast`?

Comment: @PierreDuc : I am not going to use broadcast , I am already using it to get the object.

Comment: you can pass data using `attr` in your view like so : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546771/how-do-i-pass-multiple-attributes-into-an-angular-js-attribute-directive)

Comment: @JBNizet : i am sorry. I did try it with card too. No luck. I will correct my my mistake in question

Comment: No scope attribute is set while calling directive. May be this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- you define a scope attribute named 'card', but you use `cardObj` instead
- you use a watch that is completely unnecessary. And worse: you create a new watch every time the element is clicked
- you don't define any `card` attribute on your clickmeee element. Instead, you're placing it on another element, on which the directive is not applied
- you're passing the attribute with '@'. That works, but the directive will receive a string, containing the JSONified object, rather than the object itself
- you're not showming us where you emit an event that will initialize cardObj in the controller scope

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8r4oZA6lkNNiX0blkL7?p=preview) showing a working version of your code.

Also, note that using `bind('click')` is a bad idea. You'd better have a template in your directive and use ng-click in the template, or simply not use a directive at all and just use ng-click directly on the div element.

Answer (score 2):

Bad news. You are doing it wrong all the ways.

**Firstly**

```
card='{{cardObj}}' >
```

this one should be put in the

```
<div clickmeee ></div>
```

So you can take it as binded scope variable in your directive registration

**Secondly**

If you managed to use '@' syntax

```
card: '@'
```

it will turn your input to string, not a binded scope. Use '=' instead.

**In the end**

You dont need to use watch here:

```
scope.$watch('card', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    alert(newVal);
});
```

since scope.card is binded via '=' connector. Just simple use alert(scope.card). (Need to warn you that alert an object is not a good idea)

I have tried your code here: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pLjCrojyz3QbfZJmO14A?p=preview). Changed a litte bit by using cardObj as string for easier presentation. Does it match your work?

Answer (score -1):

You should watch the `card` object:

```
myApp.directive('clickmeee', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            card: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('card', function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            });         
        }
    };
});
```

And:

```
<div clickmeee id="feedContainer" card='{{cardObj}}'> </div>
```

Whenever the controller changes the `cardObj`, the directive's watch on `card` is triggered:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.cardObj = "test";
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry didn't notice you were binding the click event first. Updated my answer.