# AngularJS: how do I create custom directive that takes in a parameter?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, attributes, directive

I want to create a custom directive that is an attribute that requires an attribute value similar to how ng-repeat takes a list of items. For example,

```
<div myDir="{{someList}}"></div>
```

How is this done?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546771/how-do-i-pass-multiple-attributes-into-an-angular-js-attribute-directive

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            'myDir' : '@', //'@' for evaluated value of the DOM attribute, 
                           //'=' a parent scope property
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myDir', function (newVal) {
                console.log('myDir', newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

usage for evaluated value (with '@')

```
<div my-dir="{{someList}}"></div>
```

usage for property from a scope (with '=')

```
<div my-dir="someList"></div>
```

to understand difference between '@' and '=' look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/angularjs-what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope)